# Is it possible to push a lookup parameter into multiple block definitions using Autolisp

Tags: autolisp

I'll give a hypothetical example to demonstrate my problem.  Imagine that I have a lookup parameter "Color" on a dynamic block definition for a chair and I've given it the possible values of "Red", "Blue", and "Green".  Now I need to push this lookup parameter to tons and tons of other dynamic block definitions for other types of chairs.  I don't want to have to go into the UI and the block editor for each definition and add this lookup parameter.  Instead I would like to automate this by writing an Autolisp routine and passing in the different blocks.

Is this possible using Autolisp?  Is it possible using any of the other AutoCAD APIs?

Note below:

1. I want to edit different block *definitions*, not references.
2. I don't want to use a block properties table because I'm already using that for other purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No, this functionality was never exposed to the LISP API.

Whilst you can retrieve and change the values of existing dynamic block parameters (using the [`getdynamicblockproperties`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-16C8768B-2533-45FF-9CFF-FF864AC78202-htm.html) method of a block reference object), you cannot create or modify dynamic block parameters within a block *definition*, nor will such objects be visible through the Visual LISP API.

Curiously, the parameters *are* visible when interrogating the DXF data of a block definition through Vanilla AutoLISP, by inspecting the `ACAD_ENHANCEDBLOCK` dictionary found within the Extension Dictionary of the `BLOCK_RECORD` entity:

```lisp
(dictsearch
    (cdr
        (assoc 360
            (entget
                (cdr
                    (assoc 330
                        (entget
                            (tblobjname "block" "YourDynamicBlockName")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    "acad_enhancedblock"
)
```

However, this area of DXF data is entirely undocumented and could likely produce unexpected and unstable results if modified directly, given that it isn't officially supported by the API.